# Using ConnectionString instead of TAdoConnection on a TAdoQuery

Tags: delphi, ado

I have derived my own component from TAdoQuery in Delphi.  I have overridden the **DoAfterPost** procedure; and in this code I create another query for the purpose of fetching the primary key associated with an inserted record (i.e. **SELECT @@IDENTITY** for SqlServer, **SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()** for MySql, etc).

In the past I always used **TAdoConnection** for database connectivity.  And in the "subquery" call made within DoAfterPost there was no problem because it was the SAME **Session** (these queries to retrieve last inserted primary keys assume a persistent database connection).

I recently made an option where instead of using a **TAdoConnection** connection, I am instead setting the **ConnectionString** property (for multi-thrading purposes).  But this creates a problem because the spawned  *subquery* does not use the same session as the main query.  Hence it does not return the primary key value.

My question is, does TAdoQuery have any **Connection** property if the **ConnectionString** is used?  I could then *daisychain* this connection/session to my subquery.  Or is the only way to accomplish this via a TAdoConnection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@M Schenkel, when you set the [`ConnectionString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.ConnectionString) property of the [`TADOQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOQuery) component, the TAdoQuery create a new connection to the database with a new session id.

the [`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) SQL Server function return the last-inserted identity value in the **current session** , because that you need to use the same Connection (and session) for the insert statement and the query `SELECT @@IDENTITY`.

As workaround in sql server you can use the [`IDENT_CURRENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) function wich is not limited to an session.

In MySql the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function also works on a perconnection. therefore the behavior is similar to the function `@@IDENTITY`.

In short, the best option you have is to use an unique `TAdoConnection` object.

Comment: Thank you.  Very helpful.  So it seems there is NO WAY to retain the session object.  I will follow up and apply the unique TAdoConnection method.